# Android - Animating layout using align-parent (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am needing to animate a layout from bottom to the top of the screen when the user taps on an EditText within that layout.  Here is my code for doing this:

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener() { _, focused ->
    if (focused) {
        val animation = object: Animation() {
            override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                val params = myLayout.getLayoutParams() as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
                myLayout.setLayoutParams(params)
            }
        }
        animation.duration = 1000
        myEditText.startAnimation(animation)
    }
}
```

When I tap on the EditText, the "myLayout" properly goes to the top of the screen.  However, two issues:

1) There is no animation, it just jumps to the top.  I am wanting it to "slide" up to the top.

2) More importantly, the views that are set to be "below" and relative to the myLayout do not go up with it.  I know those are set properly, since when I add in the top alignment in the XML, they go up with it.  But programatically it seems they stay down below the screen, still hidden.

I tried a different approach using ObjectAnimator, manually moving all the views up:

```
val anims = AnimatorSet();
val anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myLayout, View.TRANSLATION_Y, -1000f)
val anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutBelow, View.TRANSLATION_Y, -1000f)
val anim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutBelowBelow, View.TRANSLATION_Y, -1000f)
anims.playTogether(anim1, anim2, anim3)
anims.start()
```

Doing that makes the animation work, but the views below "myLayout" are still invisible!  I'm curious if it makes a difference that they are off-screen initially (?)

Thoughts on what I may be missing?  If there's a better way to handle this, I'm open to different approaches as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of animations can be done via `Transition API` which is now available in `androix` package.

Here is example where `Button` is `centerVertical` in `RelativeLayout`. `TextView` aligned to be below `Button`. After button click I remove `centerVertical` rule and add `alignParentTop` rule to `Button`. All animations can be done in almost 1 line.

```
import androidx.transition.AutoTransition;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(btn -> {
        animate(btn);
    });
}

private void animate(View button) {
    RelativeLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    AutoTransition transition = new AutoTransition();
    transition.setDuration(2000);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
    button.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="bottom text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]